# Exchanging data between two threads or not?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have function called from a different thread. And it creats a list of objects and now I need to return it to the main thread. How do I do this? Or can I just create the list of objects in the main thread and manipulate it in the separate thread?

```
Main thread
Thread t = new Thread(Quote);
t.Start(workList);
```

---

```
private void Quote(object obj)
{ 
       List<Work> works = new List<Work>();
       works = (List<Work>)obj;

       foreach (Work w in works)
       {
           //do something w 
       }

       //return works to main thread
}
```

Comment: If you use a Backgroundworker, you can pass the processed object in the WorkerCompleted event, check out this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share the List resource across your thread but you'll be responsible about the synchronization, List objects are not thread safe.
Use this snippet of code

```
Thread t = new Thread(Quote);
t.Start();
private List<Work> workList = new List<Work>(); // Shared across the threads, they should belong to the same class, otherwise you've to make it public member

private void Quote()
{ 
     lock(workList) // Get a lock on this resource so other threads can't access it until my operation is finished
     {
         foreach (Work w in works)
         {
           // do something on the workList items
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) in C# 4.0. It is **thread-safe**.

In one thread:

```
 myBlockingCollection.Add(workItem);
```

In another thread:

```
 while (true)
 {
     Work workItem = myBlockingCollection.Take();
     ProcessLine(workItem);
 }
```